# Nested IF() statement with FIND() text is returning #VALUE error

Tags: excel, if-statement

The basic need is to evaluate a cell [@[Products Purchased]] and return one of 3 values ("HF", "H", or "F") based on the text. I am using `FIND()` since I don't think `IF()` allows wildcards.

The issue is that only the first value "HF" is ever returned if TRUE. If FALSE then I get the #VALUE error.  The nested `IF()` statements work fine by themselves in other columns except for the fact that a FALSE will return the same #VALUE error.

The formula:
`=IF(AND(FIND("ish",[@[Products Purchased]])>1,FIND("unt",[@[Products Purchased]])>0),"HF", IF(FIND("ish",[@[Products Purchased]])>0,"F",IF(FIND("unt",[@[Products Purchased]])>0,"H",NA())))`

Comment: if `FIND` does not find the value it will return an error not a number.  If any part of the AND returns an error the AND returns that error and if the AND returns that error the IF will return that error.  Instead of `>0` on the FINDs, wrap them in `ISNUMBER(...)` this way an error will return `FALSE` and not an error.

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks, that worked.  I actually figured that out right as you posted. 
Post the answer if you want and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIND returns the relative starting number of the matched string or an error if the string is not found.

Instead of `>0` we need to use `ISNUMBER()` to test if the value was found in the string:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND("ish",[@[Products Purchased]])),ISNUMBER(FIND("unt",[@[Products Purchased]]))),"HF", IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ish",[@[Products Purchased]])),"F",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("unt",[@[Products Purchased]])),"H",NA())))
```